# ASP MVC Exceptions not bubbling to DelegatingHandler

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, exception

I have a basic `DelegatingHandler`:

```
internal class ExceptionVerifier : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try {
            return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // handle exception
        }
    }
}
```

However, some exceptions are not bubbling. Exception inherited from `HttpResponseException` are translated into a `HttpResponseMessage` from the [`Response`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.httpresponseexception.response(v=vs.118).aspx#P:System.Web.Http.HttpResponseException.Response) property, then returned by `base.SendAsync`. I'm not doing that anywhere. Who is doing this? Is there a way to force all exceptions to bubble?

I prefer this design because it's more clear, rather than using an `IExceptionHandler` which is called by who-knows-who, who-knows-when.